# How do I get my navbar to move towards the edges

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, nav

I'm just making a regular navbar but would like for the logo and links to fill the whole container instead of starting in the middle.I know it's an easy solution but the only way I thought would to put a margin on them but it also spreads out my links

[image: my img is below]

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background: pink;
    
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.logo{
color: whitesmoke;
text-transform:uppercase ;
letter-spacing: 5px;
font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 25%;
   
}


li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-links a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}
```

Comment: removing `justify-content: space-around;` from  nav  should do the trick

Comment: when I do that all of the nav links move to the side that Logo is on. I want the logo to start on the left and for the links to start on the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
nav {
  display: flex; 
  background: tomato;
  padding: 1rem
}

.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#" class="logo">I am the logo</a>
    <div>
      <a href="#">link 1</a>
      <a href="#">link 2</a>
      <a href="#">link 3</a>
      <a href="#">link 4</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: worked perfectly but do you mind explaining why putting margin-right on the logo also affects the links??Just so I have a better understanding

Comment: by setting the margin-right auto, I am saying use all the remaining space. the links are not being affected, the margin pushes them. you can accomplish the same result by adding a span  between logo and links with following css rule flex:1

Comment: Also I know this is unrelated but I cant pm you and would just like to know if youre starting a image gallery from scratch whats the best way to do it. Flexbox, Grid system or tr

Comment: Grid is the best solution, but its support is the problem. I would use both Grid and Flexbox. You can check if Grid is supported in css just google how to do that. if it is not supported, use Flexbox as the fallback (keep in mind that you have to maintain this). and the last solution is to use a css library like tailwind